# How do I enable Confidential Transactions?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli

I understood that Confidential Transactions was included in the last fork but not on by default. How do I enable it for my txs?

Comment: They will be enabled at v4, currently scheduled for december.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This release said it contained Ring Confidential Transactions. Do you why or what was meant by that?

Comment: Because the client is already ready (has all the code) for the next HF and activation of RCT on the network. You could use it with testnet to check out how it will work, I suppose.

Comment: The code needed for a fork is put in the binary in advance, so people have time to update before the code gets enabled. Not doing so would mean the fork would only have little hash rate, and would fail.

Comment: Thanks you have answered my question. Why didn't you make an official answer so that I can mark this question as "solved"?

Comment: I wasn't sure if there was something special you will have to do to make RCT transaction. Looks like it will be by default so I've posted an answer now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code for RCT has been included, but the network still doesn't allow RCT transactions. If my (basic) understanding of the [code](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/f195a447ccf1a26eba8aaf7560e6bfc902db6f77/src/wallet/wallet2.cpp#L3247) is correct, starting from the V4 fork, RCT transactions will be performed by default if using software ver. 0.10., so there will be nothing special that you need to do.

However, old non-RCT transactions will still be allowed, for those using ver. 0.9.4., and after V5 fork those will not be allowed anymore and it will be possible to use only RCT transactions. Note that your funds will be safe and there's nothing special you will need to do to "convert" except be running the latest software.

For some details on how/when the V4 fork will be rolled-out, see [here](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1810/how-will-the-rct-fork-be-rolled-out).